# Need MsgBox to display excel cells next to cells in an array

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the code:

```
For R = 5 To 145
  If Worksheets("CHPSpecs").Cells(R, 4).Value >= 0.9 * CHPSize And Worksheets("CHPSpecs").Cells(R, 4).Value <= 1.1 * CHPSize Then
     j = 0
     ReDim Preserve eleOutput(j)
     eleOutput(j) = Worksheets("CHPSpecs").Cells(R, 3).Value
  End If
Next R

For j = LBound(eleOutput) To UBound(eleOutput)
  If eleOutput(j) <= compareNum Then
    MsgBox ???????
  End If
Next j
```

I took away some of the code for better viewing, but this is the chunk I'm having troubles with. So I'm having VBA look down a specified column and if the value in those cells match the criteria, then they get stored in an array called `eleOutput(j)`.

Then, I want to compare the array to a variable `compareNum` and if this the If statement is true, I want to `MsgBox` the cells next to the cells that are contained in the array `eleOutput(j)`.

Assuming everything is declared and the `If statements` are done correctly, what do I put in place of `???????` to have the code output what I want? (Edit: I want to output value of the cell one column to the left of the corresponding array element)

Answer (score 2):

Try this which was just based on what you want done in your question.
First approach is abandoning array and use `Range Objects` instead.
The second approach is using a 2D array.

```
Dim eleOutput As Range, c As Range

With Sheets("CHPSpecs")
    For R = 5 To 145
        If .Cells(R, 4).Value >= 0.9 * CHPSize _
        And .Cells(R, 4).Value <= 1.1 * CHPSize Then
            If eleOutput Is Nothing Then
                Set eleOutput = .Cells(R, 3)
            Else
                Set eleOutput = Union(eleOutput, .Cells(R, 3))
            End If
        End If
    Next R
End With

For Each c In eleOutput
    If c.Value <= compareNum Then
        MsgBox c.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next
```

I'm not sure why you need to store the values compared.
In my opinion, you can do it directly if you just want to show the value in a `MsgBox` like this:

```
With Sheets("CHPSpecs")
    For R = 5 To 145
        If .Cells(R, 4).Value >= 0.9 * CHPSize _
        And .Cells(R, 4).Value <= 1.1 * CHPSize Then
            If .Cells(R, 3) <= compareNum Then
                MsgBox .Cells(R, 4).Value2
            End If
        End If
    Next R
End With
```

Another way is to pass both columns in the array creating a 2D array like this:

```
Dim eleOutput as Variant

eleOutput = Sheets("CHPSpecs").Range("C5:D145")

For j = LBound(eleOutput, 1) To UBound(eleOutput, 1)
    If eleOutput(j, 2) >= 0.9 * CHPsize _
    And eleOutput(j, 2) <= 1.1 * CHPsize Then
        If eleOutput(j, 1) <= compatenum Then
            MsgBox eleOutput(j, 2)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Again, as you can see I made the comparison directly if your sole purpose is to display it.
Otherwise, you'll have to transfer it in another array, which you can use in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which cells you are trying to display when you write *the cells next to the cells that are contained in the array `eleOutput(j)`*. I will assume you mean the cell to the right of each `eleOutput(j)` cell, but you may need to make adjustments if my assumption is incorrect.

The best way would be to store the `Range` object in you array instead of only the `Value`. When you use `Range.Value` to get the value of the cell, you no longer have a reference to the cell itself.

As this is a subset of a larger subroutine, you may need to make some adjustments to `eleObject` elsewhere or use a new array entirely to store these `Range` objects.

After you've allowed `eleObject` to store `Range` rather than `Range.Value` (`Variant`), you could do something like this:

```
j = 0 ' Moved before loop
For R = 5 To 145
  If Worksheets("CHPSpecs").Cells(R, 4).Value >= 0.9 * CHPSize And Worksheets("CHPSpecs").Cells(R, 4).Value <= 1.1 * CHPSize Then
     ReDim Preserve eleOutput(j)
     eleOutput(j) = Worksheets("CHPSpecs").Cells(R, 3) ' Note that .Value has been removed
  End If
Next R

For j = LBound(eleOutput) To UBound(eleOutput)
  If eleOutput(j).Value <= compareNum Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("CHPSpecs").Cells(eleOutput(j).Row, eleOutput(j).Column + 1).Value ' Assuming cell is one position to the right
  End If
Next j
```

As described in the comments by @BranislavKollár, you are assigning `j = 0` each iteration of this loop. Instead, you could move `j = 0` above the start of the loop. I've edited my answer to show the new placement of this assignment.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! Yes, I wanted to MsgBox the cell to the left of each eleOutput(j) cell so your answer definitely took me in the right direction.

There is now a new problem. After running the code, I get an "invalid qualifier" error and eleOutput(j).Row is highlighted in yellow. 

Any ideas how to fix this? @grovesNL

Comment: @MichaelL: It is difficult for me to test this to confirm, but I would check the value of `eleOutput(j).Row` when you receive the error message. You may be trying to use an invalid cell reference or similar. `eleOutput(j)` should be a valid range in your worksheet.

Comment: To simplify the message box, i.e. `MsgBox eleOutput(j).offset(0,-1).value`. As for the error, as @grovesNL said, the `eleOutput(j)` should be a valid range. And just another hint, you realize that your array `eleOutput(j)` is always **1 item big**, `j = 0`? The `j` does not change in the first loop. Add a counter after the assignment of values `j=j+1`.

Comment: @BranislavKollár: Thanks! I purposely used `Cells` for the offset here in case it was one of the other adjacent cells (or multiple cells). `Offset` works great too, of course.